# Problema con consumo de servicio

Tags: javascript, json, api, rest, seguridad

Quiero consumir esta Api rest http://araucaria.tidnode.cl/api/v1/login pero no me trae el key para poder traer bien la información. Este es el JSON para probar

```
{   "email": "candidato@tidnode.cl",   "password": "candidato2017" }
```

Aquí les dejo la documentación acerca del servicio http://araucaria.tidnode.cl/api/v1/docs

Comment: Cómo estrás tratando de enviar el request? Estás usando un cliente de API o algo como CURL?

Comment: Verifica cómo lo estás haciendo, porque a mi si me funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Deberías revisar tu llamada ajax, ya que si pruebas el servicio con esos datos que pasaste si funciona bien mira:

[image: Probe el servicio de login con los datos que proporcionaste]

Posiblemente uno de los parámetros no lo estas cachando bien. Y si el parámetro que buscas no viene aquí entonces creo que el API no esta funcionando y deberías revisar con el equipo de soporte de esa empresa.

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias, revisé el ajax y me funcionó.

Comment: Gabriel. Si te resultó útil la respuesta de iNavc deberías aceptar la respuesta, y no usar los comentarios para decir gracias. Más detalles en [¿Qué hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)